# Can't see files/directories in a Windows shared server on my Mac

Tags: windows, macos, mac, smb, windows-server

I'm trying to connect to my corporate work shared server on my Mac (I use windows on my work).

I have to connect with the VPN and then I'm writing the route it shows on the Windows PC in to the "connect to server".

It asks me my corporate username and password (sometimes, not always, don't know why), and then it connects succesfully, then I go into 2 folders, and the 3rd seems to be empty, but in my Windows PC it shows more folders, don't know what I'm doing wrong.

What I saw is that the last folder seems to have a different route, I'm attaching screenshots.

The server I connect:
[image: The server I connect]

The folder 1:
[image: The folder 1]

The folder I don't see anything:
[image: The folder I don't see anything]

The same folder as 2nd pic in Windows:
[image: The same folder as 2nd pic in Windows]

The same folder as 3rd pic in windows where it shows the files:
[image: The same folder as 3rd pic in windows where it shows the files]

I don't know which link I have to write:
[image: I don't know which link I have to write]

The route it shows the folder that doesnt shows anything:
[image: The route it shows the folder that doesnt shows anything]

Comment: Are you sure the permissions on the 3rd folder are correct?

Comment: I think I'm using the same user than in my windows, name.surname and password and I also tried my email one: name.surname@company.es and password how I can know the exact user I use in windows that has the permissions?